# Choosing RC car motor that can be driven with the Raspberry Pi

Tags: gertboard

I bought this [cheap aluminum robotics platform.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008Q47VKE)

Long story short the motors that were included are worthless, so I'm pretty much stuck with a frame. However, this is a nice aluminum frame, "good enough for me" and I plan on using it. I would like to order my own motors but have some questions in regards to what type of motor I need.

First thing is I'm going to make this all wheel drive. So I assume I'll need four motors one for each wheel. If anyone can suggest a different setup please let me know.

Second, what type of motor and size do I need? It's a fairly light weight platform approximately 620 grams. In regards to what "type", I mean do I go with brushless or steppers or something else. As for size, brushless motors have a kV rating. I know the lower the kV the higher the torque but higher kV the more speed. I don't really have a preference but would just like a suggestion.

Finally, this will be controlled through a Pi. Therefore, I'm pretty sure I'll need a motor shield to connect to the Pi, LiPo Battery (Rechargeable), and a ESC speed controller. I've never messed around with any of these items so I could use some guidance on the right kind of ESC and motor shield.

Comment: I have that frame and find those motors ample for robotics tasks like line following, wall following etc. Why do you find them inadequate? What do you want to achieve? Are you looking for better speed? Carrying ability?

Comment: i want more speed and uphill ablity also i'll be mounting a mini robotic arm eventually. Therefore, weight will be coming into play.

Comment: Have you read the manual? It shows you an alternative using standard DC gear motor. 2 motors might be enough if they are more powerful. Steering is not ideal with these fixed wheels. Don't use steppers. Brushed are easiest to connect. Brushless require driver circuitry/IC.